# how to build a summary variable using multiple col info

Tags: r

I have a data that looks like this:

[image]
it can be build using codes:

```
df<-structure(list(`Hobby 1` = c("Drawing", NA, "Singing", "drawing"
), `Hobby 2` = c(NA, NA, "reading", "singing"), `Hobby 3` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, "reading")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Is it a way I can build a summary varaible for it that will looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Please paste the actual tables here instead of images. (Yes, [Stack Overflow has support for tables now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356997/1968)!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`unite` from ‘tidyr’](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/unite.html) does this almost out of the box:

```
〉df %>% unite(Hobby, `Hobby 1` : `Hobby 3`, sep = ', ', na.rm = TRUE)
# A tibble: 4 x 1
  Hobby
  <chr>
1 "Drawing"
2 ""
3 "Singing, reading"
4 "drawing, singing, reading"
```

So, with minimal post-processing:

```
df %>%
    unite(
        Hobby, `Hobby 1` : `Hobby 3`,
        sep = ', ',
        na.rm = TRUE,
        remove = FALSE
    ) %>%
    mutate(Hobby = ifelse(nzchar(Hobby), paste('Hobby:', Hobby), 'No Hobby'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, in base R:

```r
df$Hobby <- paste("Hobby:", sub("NA", "None", gsub(", NA", "", 
            apply(df, 1, paste, collapse = ", "))))

df
#>   Hobby 1 Hobby 2 Hobby 3                            Hobby
#> 1 Drawing    <NA>    <NA>                   Hobby: Drawing
#> 2    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>                      Hobby: None
#> 3 Singing reading    <NA>          Hobby: Singing, reading
#> 4 drawing singing reading Hobby: drawing, singing, reading
```